# Prove that $\sqrt2-\sqrt5$ is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I've attempted this proof through contradiction and just wanted to check whether I did this correctly.

Assume that the claim is false, that is

$\sqrt2 - \sqrt5$ = $\frac {a}{b}$

Now square both sides

$2 - 5$ = $\frac {a^2}{b^2}$

$-3$ = $\frac {a^2}{b^2}$

$-3b^2$ = $a^2$

This is impossible as $a^2$ cannot be negative, so this is a contradiction.

Is this proof valid?

Comment: If this proof were valid it would prove that $\sqrt2 - \sqrt5$ is not even a real number, because the square of a real number is never negative.

Comment: $(\sqrt 2 - \sqrt 5) = 2 + 5 -2\sqrt{10}$.  Not $2 -5$.

Comment: You should have noticed something was wrong when you  attempted to  square  a real number and got $(-3)$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Your squaring must be: $$(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab$$

Comment: Thank you, I see my problem now.

Comment: @Kermitty If you feel your question has been resolved, please give the answer a “\color{green}\checkmark$ so this question can be removed from the unanswered box. (You’ll also get +2 rep.)

Comment: Sonnhard, I missed you man! I am one of the fans of your answers on AoPS forums!

Comment: Nice to meet you! I'm working daily on mathematical problems!

Answer (score 3):

$(\sqrt{2}$ - $\sqrt{5})^2$ is not equal to 2 - 5; but rather, $2 - 2\sqrt{10} + 5$ = $7 - 2\sqrt{10}$

Answer (score 0):

If

$\sqrt 2 - \sqrt 5 \in \Bbb Q, \tag 0$

then

$\sqrt 2 - \sqrt 5 = \dfrac{r}{s}, \; r, s \in \Bbb Z;  \tag 1$

we square:

$7 - 2\sqrt{10} = 2 - 2\sqrt{10} + 5 = \dfrac{r^2}{s^2}, \tag{2}$

and re-arrange to find

$\sqrt{10} = \dfrac{1}{2}\left (7 - \dfrac{r^2}{s^2} \right ) \in \Bbb Q; \tag 3$

we may then conclude with the aid of the following well-known

***Theorem:***  Let $2 \le m, n \in \Bbb N$ be natural numbers.  Then $\sqrt[m] n \in \Bbb Q$ if and only if $n$ is a perfect $m$-th power, in which case $\sqrt[m] n \in \Bbb N$.

***Proof of Theorem:***  The "if" direction is self evident; as for the "only if" direction,
we may suppose that

$\sqrt[m] n = \dfrac{r}{s}, \; r, s \in \Bbb Z, \tag 4$

with

$\gcd(r, s) = 1; \tag 5$

note we may safely assume

$s \ne \pm 1 \tag{5.5}$

since in the contrary case (4) becomes

$\sqrt[m] n = \pm r \Longrightarrow n = (\pm r)^m, \tag{5.6}$

i.e., $n$ is a perfect $m$-th power.

From (4) we have

$r^m = ns^m, \tag 6$

from which it follows that

$s \mid r^m; \tag 7$

now by virtue of (5) we have, *via* Bezout's identity, $a, b \in \Bbb Z$ such that

$ar + bs = 1; \tag 8$

multiplying this equation through by $r^{m - 1}$ we obtain

$ar^m + bsr^{m - 1} = r^{m - 1}; \tag 9$

since

$s \mid r^m, \; s \mid bsr^{m - 1}, \tag{10}$

(9) yields

$s \mid r^{m - 1}; \tag{11}$

we may now replace (7) with (11) and continue repeating the process expressed in (8)-(11), each time decrementing $m$ by $1$ until $m = 2$ is reached (the reader may construct a simple inductive argument to formalize this process if he or she so desires); at this point (11) becomes

$s \mid r, \tag{12}$

but by virtue of (5.5) this contradicts (5); therefore (4) is impossible and hence

$\sqrt [m]n \notin \Bbb Q. \tag{13}$

***End:  Proof of Theorem.***

Applying this theorem with $n = 10$, $m = 2$ we see that

$\sqrt{10} \notin \Bbb Q \tag{14}$

in contradiction to (3)and hence

$\sqrt 2 - \sqrt 5 \notin \Bbb Q \tag{15}$

as well.

Answer (score -2):

you square it wrong

if you wish to get 2-5 multiple by square root of 2 + square root of 5

but now be could have written the original question as (sqrt(2)-sqrt(5))/1

now when we multiple we get -3/sqrt(2)+sqrt(5)

now square this equation you get 4.5/sqrt(10) as sqrt(10) is irrational so division is also irrational so the square root of the equation is also irrational

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Comment: Welcome to the StackExchange community. Please do calculations before you post an answer.